# Sumar datos no repetidos en consulta

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT(suma(venta.LineTotal)) AS telemercadeo FROM dbo.MAVIJU_DASHBOARD_VENTAS_ANL_VTA venta 
join dbo.acrd cliente on venta.cardCode = cliente.cardCode WHERE venta.NombreVendedor = 'Telemercadeo' 
and venta.fecha BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-29' and cliente.slpcode = 45
```

Buenas tardes, quisiera saber la forma correcta de realizar una suma de valores no distintos debido a que el select adjuntado me hace la suma de valores que son distintos y obtengo una cantidad errónea, gracias de antemano

Comment: Para saber que esta mal, necesitamos saber que resultado esperas, que resultado te da, y con que datos... asi como esta.. dificil saber que falla

Comment: Deseo el siguiente resultado: 6375.48 pero obtengo una cantidad mayor 19282382.90 debido a que suma los repetidos

Comment: el distinct ira adentro entonces? yo no veo ningun group ni nada que quite los distintos.. sigue siendo dificil ayudarte asi...

Comment: Por ese motivo hago mi consulta, es porque quisiera que me orienten. Solo quisiera saber como sumo el campo venta.linetotal que tiene valores repetidos, pero quiero mi suma sin esos valores reptidos, se que mi consulta esta mal, por algo la consulto por este medio

Comment: Lo que te estoy diciendo, es que falta informacion para poder ayudarte.. es raro que tengas valores repetidos que no quieras sumas... salvo que tu tabla sea rara... y vuelvo a decirte lo que ya te dije.. con el distinct adentro del sum no anda?

Comment: Si anda, pero el problema es que suma valores repetidos (quiero eviitar esos valores repetidos, no es error de que salgan valores, es parte de la consulta, solo quiero evitar esos valores repetidos), sin el sum me doy cuenta sumando manualmente que obtengo un resultado diferente que al hacer una suma en el select.

Comment: Te hago una pregunta.. realmente necesitas el join? puede ser que el join sea quien te duplique los valores y la consulta que estas haciendo no parece necesitarlo, porque solo buscas algo que podria solucionarse con un IN

Comment: Necesito obtener las ventas de telemercadeo que ha hecho un vendedor, MAVIJU_DASHBOARD_VENTAS_ANL_VTA es la tabla de ventas y acrd es la tabla historica de clientes, entonces por esa razon es que las uno debido a que en cliente se que vendedor ha hecho ventas de telemercadeo y sumo sus ventas de la tabla ventas pertenecientes a telemercadeo

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema no es el DISTINCT, es que estas usando mal el join.

Tu join une todos los registros que estan en MAVIJU_DASHBOARD_VENTAS_ANL_VTA con todos los registros de acrd por venta.cardCode = cliente.cardCode.

Con lo cual, si hay mas de un cliente.cardCode igual, entonces va a duplicar la cantidad de registros que trae de la tabla ventas.

Para que esto no pase, evitemos el join que no aporta nada y hagamos una consulta directa a los datos que necesitamos, poniendo como restriccion tu clausula de join

```
SELECT sum(venta.LineTotal) AS telemercadeo 
FROM dbo.MAVIJU_DASHBOARD_VENTAS_ANL_VTA venta 
WHERE venta.NombreVendedor = 'Telemercadeo' 
    and venta.fecha BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-29' 
    and venta.cardCode in (select cardCode from dbo.acrd where slpcode = 45)
```

Comment: Gracias fue de gran ayuda tu respuesta :D